# How to return an array of characters in cypher program (python3)

Tags: python, ascii, chr, ord

i wrote code when input for example is "a" he return "h". But how i can make it work if i want to return array of characters, for example if is input "aa"
to return "hh"?

```
def input(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        ci = (ord(s[i])-90)%26+97
        s = "".join(chr(ci))
    return s
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strings to do this. My variable finaloutput is a string that I will use to store all the updated characters.

```python
def foo(s):
    finaloutput = ''
    for i in s:
        finaloutput += chr((ord(i)-90)%26+97)
    return finaloutput
```

This code uses string concatenation to add together a series of characters. Since strings are iterables, you can use the for loop shown above instead of the complex one that you used.

Comment: Thank you Arunav.

Answer (score 1):

Never use built-in names as `input`

```
l = []


def input_x(s):
    for i in s:
        i = (ord(i)-90)%26+97
        l.append(chr(i))
    s = ''.join(l)
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def input_x(s):
    result = ""
    for i in s:
        ci = (ord(i)-90)%26+ 97
        result += chr(ci)
    print(result)
```